# Sync my calendar app with other calendars

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, icloud, caldav

I want to have a real-time sync in my calendar application with other calendar applications (Yahoo Calendar, Google Calendar, iCloud Calendar, Microsoft Exchange and Microsoft Outlook). Is there any way to do it?
i know that we can do it for google calendar, but i am looking to find a way to do it for all calendars.
[CalDav4j](https://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/) is a java library implementing the [CalDAV](http://caldav.calconnect.org/index.html) protocol and we can use it with a CalDav Server like [Radicale](http://www.radicale.org/) but it's not support microsoft calendars.
Can i use [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) for it?
I need a solution for sync all calendars(such as a library) or an example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of android is to decouple calendar UI from calendar sync adapters. You find Google and Exchange calendar sync built into android. For everything else you need a sync adapter, which you'll find in play store for calDAV, iCloud, outlook.com, etc. Each sync protocol would need to be implemented by yourself, you probably don't want that. While you might find open source libraries handling some of the standards, they don't give you the in-depth knowledge on how to handle Android especially its older versions where the calendar API wasn't official yet.