# Sync custom calendar activity with other email services in NodeJS

Tags: reactjs, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, caldav

Right now, I am designing a custom react calendar, with NestJS as backend support and what I am trying to achieve is to sync my calendar with other online calendar service like google calendar, outlook, zoho calendar, iCalendar or any other calendar service. 
Right now I am looking at [calDAV](http://caldav.calconnect.org/index.html) service and from what I gathered, I only found the calDAV api for google (which I am yet to implement) but I'm not understanding how I can integrate other email services as well.
 It would be really helpful if the community can guide me on my track on which and how to use [calDAV](http://caldav.calconnect.org/index.html) or any other services which can be helpful in my case.

Comment: I just found this post having the same problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499016/sync-my-calendar-app-with-other-calendars?rq=1